# How to hide query params when using Redirect View in SpringBoot?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using the below **RedirectView** class while calling a RestEnd point in my code.

```
RedirectView view = new RedirectView("/test/url?param1=" + value1 + "&param2=" + value2);
    view.setHttp10Compatible(false);
    view.setExposePathVariables(false);
```

By doing the above change I expected that the query params present in the url are not visible since i have set **setExposePathVariable**. But still I could see them in the url of browser. So, is there a way to hide query params in the url ? Any suggestions for me to try out to get my desired result ?

Comment: Why would you want to hide them in the first place? A redirection needs to change the URL and do a new GET request, using those variables, I don't see how you would hide them

Comment: I have some important info which is being shown currently in the browser  URL(not a password). I can try out a POST call but it would require a change in multiple applications which currently we arent planning. So, thinking whether a RedirectView would help (which is what the common application has currently)

Comment: You can try using headers to obfuscate this data, but it will still be visible from the browser, just not directly in the URL bar